# Simple chat application using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make simple chat application. I have already made relationship b/w user and chat_message using model.  Just I want to know that when I am sending message to any user message is not sending in private chat. How can I do this?

**Database**

1. User: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEaR2.png
2. Chat Mesasge: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI2Zs.png

**User Model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
   public function Chats()   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Chat_message','id','to_user_id');
   }
}
```

**Chat_message**

```
class Chat_message extends Model{
   public function user(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
   }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function chat($id){          
    $single_chat = User::with('Chats')->where('id',$id)->first();
    return $single_chat;          
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/chat/{id}','HomeController@chat');
```

**result**

```
{"id":1,"name":"zubairMukhtar","email":"zubairmukhtar1992@gmail.com","email_verified_at":null,"job":null,"phone_number":null,"created_at":"2020-02-12 06:49:12","updated_at":"2020-02-12 06:49:12","chats":[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to fetch `chat_messages` data group by `from_user_id`, so that you will get all `chat_messages` data separated by user who sent a message, and based on you need to display those message on separate window.

Currently as per your current query you will get all messages on same window, so it will display all messages on same screen!

Hope this help!